# Should I divide my table into simpler ones or should I leave it the way it is?

Tags: database-design

I have a table which must store data related to an examination
The structure of the table is as follows

Table name: Exam_Routine

```
| Year |  Date   |Stream | Paper_Code
```

Since I have noticed that there will be only 4 values for`year`in the entire table, I decide d to decompose my table into four different tables featuring different years as

Table name: Exam_RoutineYear_1

```
| Date   |Stream | Paper_Code
```

Table name: Exam_RoutineYear_2

```
| Date   |Stream | Paper_Code
```

Table name: Exam_RoutineYear_3

```
| Date   |Stream | Paper_Code
```

Table name: Exam_RoutineYear_4

```
| Date   |Stream | Paper_Code
```

Is this a better option? or the first one is better? which one will be more helpful.

Comment: The first one is **much** better

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please tell my the reason how will it help?

Comment: Search for "database normalization"

Comment: And what about people who do Master's degrees? Those who repeat years - i.e. Year_3.1, 3.2....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, breaking the table up that way is generally not a good idea unless you are talking about table partitioning in which case you have just one table as far as the overall design is concerned and the partitioning is a performance/administration difference.

With a separate distinct table per year you have the following problems, amongst others:

- To query based on more than on year you have to `UNION` the tables back together (or take some other extra steps) which will make the resulting queries less efficient and less easy to maintain.
- If extra years are needed later you will have to add new tables and update any views/procedures/queries/other that refer to multiple years as in the above point.
- You will need to enforce (by adding database constraints if supported by the DB you are using or in your business logic) that the right rows go in the right tables which adds complexity.